# What type in typescript should be used for objects whose fields are not known at compile time?

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following function:

```
const doSomething = (param: object) => {
  // path param to another function/library
}
```

The point is that I know (and want to enforce) that `param` is an object, not primitive type. In typescript `object` [fulfils](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object) this role.

I noticed however that:

```
const a: object = {
  test: 5
}
console.log(a.test)
```

gives a typescript error: `Property 'test' does not exist on type 'object'.` Does this mean that `object` should only be used for empty objects?

I'm wondering what is the best practice to declare object variables in typescript where the exact fields of the object are not know at compile time. I noticed that:

```
const b: Record<string, any> = {
    test: 5
}

console.log(b.test)
```

doesn't result in an error. So should `Record` type be preferred instead of `object`?

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhiARgKwKbFgXhgbwFgAoGGKDaJAVhIF8TRIQAbDAOhZAHMAKOdhWgBKEo3DQYKJACUsIAE4ATADzQFASzDcANPDABPAHww8RUmXKUoNemOJMIrDlz4pB14UA)

Comment: What you have with `object` is the right behaviour, no? You don't know at compile time what fields it has, so accessing `a.test` might leave you with `undefined`. You could use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to check whether it's `test`able, or a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) like `(a as any).test`.

Comment: Try `Record<string, unknown>`

Comment: "*Does this mean that object should only be used for empty objects?*" it means that TS can only ensure it's not a primitive, not whether it has or hasn't any properties.[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhiARgKwKbFgXhgbwFgAoGGKDaJAVhIF8TRJYUkAlLEAJwBMAeaFwCWYAOYAaeGACeAPhh4ipMuUpQa9EjywAbOFwwwAZgFcw2IeGMAKAB5JUmbAEokANxBCeAbhIkj1gCMzr7EAQBE4BjhIf7WUFwmGLFh1gDK0gC2KCA61uFoJtDwMBBZOToxKQH4dNXWYBgA7jAAInAU1s71cPUoIUA). If you want to access something, you need a more specific type. `Record` might be fine but perhaps there are better types for your use case.

Comment: What are you trying to do with an object whose properties you don't know? What CAN you do?

Comment: @ritaj why does it matter what is the background of this object? I didn't want to provide too many details into the nature of this object because the question is quite generic and I also wanted a generic answer. Roughly speaking, it's an object which contains some data and I then check that if certain properties exist then I manipulate the object and then pass it on to another service.

Comment: So make a generic example to answer my question. The point was you're probably asking the wrong question here. If you can make a decision based on objects' properties that must mean you can know what properties that object can possibly have in the first place, so you should be asking a different question.

Comment: @Yos the context matters here because the generic solution to your generic problem is "either use or don't use `object`" and I hope you agree - that's not a good answer here. If you *don't* want to use any object properties, then use `object`. If you want to use an object as a dictionary, use `Record`. If you want to use specific properties `a`, `b`, or `c` but don't expect all, then you can define an interface where they are optional or you may even define a union type. There are probably other solutions. That's why it matters. We cannot guess what would serve you best.

Answer (score -1):

I think two solutions for this might be either to declare that parameter as a Record, or to check for the type at runtime and throw an exception if the parameter is not an object.

For the first approach you would do so like this:

```
const doSomething = (param: Record<string, any>) => {
  // path param to another function/library
}
```

For the second approach you could do so like this:

```
const doSomething = (param: any) => {
if(typeof param !== 'object') throw new Error("Not an object")
  // path param to another function/library
}
```

But, I have to say that in case that this param comes from outside your own code (as in a framework or so) you won't be compiling that param and so your error on compile time won't be there. And in case that object is indeed declared in your own code, is not usual to run into this kind of problems when the code has been well designed.

It is a great disadvantage for you to have to bypass the TS type checking spreading `any` all over the place. Maybe with more context we can figure out what could be changed in the design so you don't have to deal with this :)